# Set content type when uploading to Azure Blob Storage

Tags: python, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I am uploading a static site using the Azure Blob storage client library.

```
        blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(az_string)
        blob_client = blob_service_client.get_blob_client(container=container_name, blob=local_file_name)
        print("\nUploading to Azure Storage as blob:\n\t" + local_file_name)

        with open('populated.html', "rb") as data:
            test = blob_client.upload_blob(data, overwrite=True)
```

This is working but the HTML file is downloading instead of displaying. This is because the content type is wrong: `Content-Type: application/octet-stream`.

Is there any way to set this using `upload_blob`?

**Update:**

To get this working, I needed this:

```
my_content_settings = ContentSettings(content_type='text/html')
blob_client.upload_blob(data, overwrite=True, content_settings=my_content_settings)
```

Comment: The update was exactly what I needed. Thanks Mick!

Comment: Thanks for the update. Wasted a day by trying to find this in the insanely bad docs.

Comment: How did you import the class `ContentSettings` ?

Comment: @harvpan `from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient, ContentSettings`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Looking at the code [`here`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/master/sdk/storage/azure-storage-blob/azure/storage/blob/_blob_client.py#L375), one of the parameters to this method is `content_settings` which is of type [`ContentSettings`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/master/sdk/storage/azure-storage-blob/azure/storage/blob/_models.py#L697). You can define `content_type` there.

Comment: in case you are looking and do not see the comment above the ContentSettings model is available from the import `from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient, ContentSettings`