# Set content type when uploading to Azure Blob Storage via Databricks

Tags: html, pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks, azure-blob-storage

I am uploading a static site using the `databricks` platform specifically using the below command for pushing `html` content to a location.

```
dbutils.fs.put("/mnt/$web/index.html", html, overwrite=True)
```

This is working but the HTML file is downloading instead of displaying. This is because the content type is wrong: Content-Type: `application/octet-stream`.

Is there any way to set this using `databricks` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, this code worked for me. First, I am getting connection string from databricks scope as

```
dbutils.secrets.get(scope = "generic-scope", key = "website-key")
```

If you don't have it then look for it inside Storage Account's Container Access Key

[image: access location in azure storage account]

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient, ContentSettings
connect_str="connectionString"
blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(connect_str)

# Instantiate a ContainerClient
container_client = blob_service_client.get_container_client("$web")

# List files in blob folder
blobs_list = container_client.list_blobs()
for blob in blobs_list:
    print(blob.content_settings.content_type) # application/octet-stream
    blob.set_http_headers(
    content_settings=ContentSettings(
        content_type="text/html; charset=utf-8"
        )
    )
```

Answer (score 2):

`dbutils.fs.put` works with files on DBFS and doesn't "know" about underlying implementation details, because you can mount different things - S3, ADLSv1/v2, etc.  Changing of the content-type is specific to the blob storage API, so you will need to implement the code in Python (for [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59752380/set-content-type-when-uploading-to-azure-blob-storage)) or Scala that will use that API to set content-type for uploaded files, or upload files & set content-type via API, without `dbutils.fs.put`.